# Exclude fields with null values in SOLR queries

Tags: solr, edismax, dismax

I am trying to make a url request to an API that uses SOLR for queries.

I have a lot of data with a lot of fields that contains different values and often some of those fields will contain a null value.

I want to make a query where I retrieve all the data where specific fields are not null, but contain some actual value.

For example each entry contains a field called tags which is an array of tags. a tag could for example be the word test.

I have tried doing -tags:[* TO *] and that results in all the data sets where tags is null to be returned.

I have also tried tags:[* TO *] that returns all data, both where tags are null and where tags are actually set.

I have been trying all sorts of things to get to the last case, where only tags with values are returned and I hope you can help me?

Comment: You could try doing a regex match on your tags field

Comment: hi @BinoyDalal could you elaborate on how that would work?

Comment: Something like `tags:/[A-Za-z0-9]+/`. I am not sure about Unicode support for the regex matcher though, but for most of the cases this should work.

Comment: Thanks,
The problem just seems to be when doing this that null values i also a valid possibility in regex so it still gets counted and show up

Comment: Ok. You could also try negating the null query. Something like `NOT -tags:[* TO *]`

Comment: By default your `tags:[* TO *]` should only return those where there is a value in that field, _as long as_ that is the _only part_ of your query. Otherwise the query for `-tags:[* TO *]` wouldn't represent the opposite set. Do you have more information about the actual query and an example of two documents that gets returned (one that should and one that shouldn't)?

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks for your comment.

Comment: @MatsLindh pressed enter to early :) here is my comment:

Thanks for your comment.
An example of my query is the following:
(type:table)and(tags:[* TO *])and(deleted:false)
This results in in 2 responses,
 one where tags is (the one we want):

"tags" : [ "somedata" ] ,

The other where tag is (the result we wanted to exclude):

"tags" : null,

Answer (score 4):

Your question is slightly confusing, because you use terms like "retrieve data" and "retrieve fields" which can be confusing. In SOLR, a query specifies which *documents* (or records) are retrieved.

If you want all the docs that have some value in the field "tags", you can use

```
(tags:*)
```

If you want all docs that do not have a value in the field "tags", then you can use:

```
(*:* AND NOT tags:*)
```

or

```
(*:* AND -tags:*)
```

Comment: hi Hugo,
Thanks for the answer, I have tried with (tags:*) and it works fine if it is just string fields, but it seems that because this is a Set, it still returns fields with null in it

Comment: Is the field perhaps **empty** not null? You can strip empty fields using a custom UpdateRequestProcessor chain.

Comment: strange, you should show us an example of such a doc... perhaps if you serialise to JSON instead of XML you'll see more clearly what the value is (you can do this with the &wt=json query parameter)

Answer (score 0):

`and` is not the same as `AND` - which is the separator you have to use in your query.

Your query probably just search for (documents with `and` somewhere in them in the default field) or (`deleted:false`) or (`tags:[* TO *]`).

Use the proper separator with spaces around it to group multiple conditions. I'd also suggest using a filter query (`fq`) for any of these that are static (such as `deleted:false`) as that allows for that query to be cached separately from your actual query.